# Как сделать такую кнопку

Tags: android

Как сделать такую кнопку в андроид приложении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С помощью картинки.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: Нарисовать, как-как, елы-палы. А всё, что касается исполнения, то гугл "как сделать кнопку в андроид приложении", легко находится и реализуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кладешь картинку img_name.jpg в папку "drawable", вставляешь в разметку:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/img_name" />
```

Comment: ок, спасибо....